# PostgreSQL - Free space in a full database

Tags: postgresql

I have a `PostgreSQL` database in a remote server. When I try to connect with `pgAdmin` I have this message :

```
server closed the connection unexpectedly This probably means the server terminated abnormally before or while processing the request.
```

With researches, I found that database and server are full, here is the result of `df` command and last `PostgreSQL` log:

[image: df]

[image: log]

As you can see, used space is 100 % and database can't execute anything. I try to stop and restart `PostgreSQL` service without any result.

What the best way to deal with this : `VACUUM` the database to free some space ? Dump it to a local folder ?

I'm running on `PostgreSQL 10` and `Debian 4.9`.

Comment: You can't VACUUM anything if the database is not running, and VACUUM generally does not free up any space immediately anyway.  See if there is any data which can be removed.  Like human readable log files, or maybe temp files which didn't get cleaned up during the crash.

Comment: Drastic method: https://duckduckgo.com/?q=copy+postgresql+cluster+to+another+drive

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the server is still running, you can try to `TRUNCATE` or `DROP` a table to create space.

If the server has crashed, you need to increase the disk space before restarting.

Comment: When I want to connect to PostgreSQL to `DROP` some tables, I have `Could not connect to the server : No such file or directory. Is the server running locally and accepting connections on Unix domain socket "var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.54321" ?`

Comment: Then the server probably crashed. Increase the disk space on the server and restart PostgreSQL.

Comment: I've just contact my hosting service to increase disk space. Wait and see.

Comment: You were right, increase disk space was the solution to fix this.